# Set the width of string array- LabVIEW

Tags: labview

How to set the width of the string array depending on the size of the maximum length of the string element in the array.

[image: pic1 shows the initial array width size (maxmimum of 3 chararcters can be seen)]

[image: string array elements are: cat, elephant, doggy, horse. here the complete string cannot be seen]

[image: string array changed manually]

This is static way to show the complete details of the array. How to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Right click a string indicator in the array and go to **Create >> Property Node >> Size >> Width**.  I would have posted a picture of the block diagram with working code to adjust the width of the array based on the longest string but I do not have enough reputation to post an image :(

Edit: Added the block diagram image.  Note that you may need to fine tune the constants to get the resizing to work under all conditions.  I did not spend much time determining them.  The number being added is there to deal with the border.

[image]

Comment: Look for the solution here: [ni forums][1]


  [1]: http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/resize-the-string-array-automatically/m-p/2880662#M837398